# evaluate mathematical expression faster for a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sympy, evaluate

I am using sympy sympify function for evaluating a formula (dynamic) for data present in a dataframe.

```
import sympy as sy

def evaluate_function(formula,dataframe):    
  gfg_exp = sy.sympify(formula)
  dataframe_dict=dataframe.to_dict()
  gfg_exp = gfg_exp.subs(dataframe_dict) 
  return gfg_exp

df['result']=df.apply(lambda row:evaluate_function(formula=condition_to_check,dataframe=row),axis=1) 

sample datadata is like:
A       B 
200     400
320     100 

formula: A/B > 1
```

This is working for small datasets (around 20k records in less time), but when dataset size is huge around 1 million records - 
its taking longer time to finish the computation.
Is there anyother way to do this process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is there a different formula for each row?  Why do you need to use sympy at all?

Comment: Yes correct. Formula is dynamic - and dataframe will have relevant columns required for that formula.

Comment: How many unique formulas are there?  Wondering if there is a way to apply each on seperate subsets of the data.

Comment: currently there are no limits on the number of formula's.

Comment: This is interesting problem is there any way you can provide more specific examples?  Like more example formulas and/or how the formulas get generated?  How large does the data set get in terms of size (shape of the dataframe).  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `lambdify` to convert your expression into a Python function, rather than using `subs`. See the documentation https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify